# SQL Server 2012 database problems

Tags: asp.net-mvc, sql-server-2012

We have a SQL Server 2012 database with our live project asset tracking system. We are facing some problems in our database including huge number of tables and more than 5 millon rows of data. Basically a problem with same some of the queries on tables (like TrackerMaster, Usercar, TrackerResponse) are taking less time to execute whereas other queries on these tables are tremendously slow to execute.

I am not sure whether it is a fragmentation problem for indexing or not. More precisely, even if  we union on two or more queries where query getting very slow to produce result on the database I don't know why it's happening

Can someone please help me resolve this issue or problem?

Comment: You Don't Need To Capitalize Each And Every Single Word In English! This makes it extremely hard to read your question.....

Comment: And without seeing *any* table structures, sample data, queries and execution plans for those queries, it's nearly **impossible** to give you any meaningful advice.....